# How can I style html/form elements using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a log in form and my html so far is:

```
<body id="login">
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="loginform">
<form id ="login" name="login" action = "" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="smart-green">    
       <h1>Login Form</h1> 
        <label>
        <span>Email Address:</span>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" />
        </label>

        <label>
        <span>Password:</span>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </label>

        <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </label> 
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to style it using CSS. How can I access:

a) the overall form to change the overall style

b) the email address title and box

c) the button

I have tried using . # > but confused myself now. It's probably a really silly mistake I'm making but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Where are you setting your css?  What is  ". # >"?

Comment: @Drops - Labels are allowed to hold inputs...it's perfectly valid HTML

Comment: @ShermanS Sorry, poor clarification on my behalf. My CSS is in a separate file and I mean I've tried accessing the elements using either .x or #x or #x.y or a combination of them all e.g. for a table further along in my code I use table#header-table td:first-child to access a single cell and for navigation I've used .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a ... etc.

Comment: @Drops Not only is it valid, but it also serves a distinct purpose.  An input that is a child of a label behaves the same way as an input/label combo using `for` and `id` (clicking the label triggers focus or changes the checked state) but without the need of the `for` and `id` attributes

Comment: @JosephMarikle Nice shortcut then, I stand corrected and have learned something new, thanks!

Comment: @Drops Glad I could help. :)  That's what SO is all about.

Comment: Now that issue is solved, If this is for production code, I'd like to suggest two things:

First is not to write your own login if you can avoid it.  It is hard to get password storage right, even MySpace and Adobe got caught doing it wrong when they were hacked. If at all possible use a service like OAuth or OpenID.

If you can't use a service, the static form here has no nounce (numbers used only once, not the British nounce), honeypot field or other protections to help detect bad actors, or brute force attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved like this
CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
form{
    text-align: center;  /* To align the form center */
    background-color: orange; /* sets the background-color to orange */
}

#password{ /* If you use class attribute, use .password{} */
        /* to modify this section*/
}

#email{
    width: 200px; /* to size the email bar*/
}

#submit_button{
    color: #fff; /* Text Color*/
    background-color: #5cb85c; /* Background color green*/ 
    border-color: #4cae4c; /* border color light green*/ 
}

</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="loginform">
<form id ="login" name="login" action = "" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="smart-green">    
       <h1>Login Form</h1> 
        <label>
        <span>Email Address:</span>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" />
        </label>
            <br /><br /><br />
        <label>
        <span>Password:</span>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </label>
            <br /><br /><br />

        <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send" />
        </label> <br /><br /><br />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how can you access:

**a) the overall form to change the overall style**
Use `#loginform {/* CSS rules */}` to address the overall style of the form container. Since there's no other element except the form, it will work as if you were targeting the form itself.

**b) the email address title and box**
use `#loginform label {/* CSS rules */}` to target the CSS rules at the label and `#email{}` to target the email input box. You can re-use this last rule for the other items by adding their IDs (e.g. `#email, #password {/* CSS rules */}`)

**c) the button**
Use `input[type=submit] {/* CSS rules */}` to style the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Or instead you can use "class" or "id" to the form,label and input field to provide them individual style.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just starting out and just want to see it working, maybe it would be simpler for you to attach an 'id' attribute to each html element, and then access them in your css that way (for the specifics you want to edit, e.g. email title, email input, submit button).

For example:

html

```
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Send" />
```

css

```
#submitBtn{ color:black   }
```

If this doesnt work,

1.) Clear you cache

2.) Make sure your css file is actually included in your html

3.) Make sure each "ID" on the page attached to an element is unique

if that doesnt work, use your dev tools and fiddle around:
hit (f12) in any browser

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the label around the input is one way to do things (and it is technically valid), the other way is to use the for attribute. The later is typically considered more acceptable to some because it avoids the need for the extra span.

```
<form id="loginform" action="" method="post">
  <div class="input">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label for="password">Passowrd</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Log On" class="btn" />
</form>
```

Would then be styled like:

```
 .input > label:after /* To place style/content after the label */
 {
   content: ':';
 }

 .input > label /* To target the label */
 {
   display:block; /* Puts the label above the input, just an example */
 }

 .input > input /* The input. */
 {
   background: yellow; /* for instance */
 }

 .input /* The whole input and label pair */
 {
   margin-bottom: 3px; /* Add space bellow each input, or whatever */
 }
```

Otherwise, nesting the input inside the label removes the need for the `for` attribute on the label element, and `id` on input element. So, if we use your HTML:

```
<body id="login">
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="loginform">
  <form id ="login" name="login" action = "" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="smart-green">    
     <h1>Login Form</h1> 
      <label>
      <span>Email Address:</span>
      <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" />
      </label>

      <label>
        <span>Password:</span>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </label>

      <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </label> 
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

We could style it like this:

```
#login > label
{
  /* Style for input pair */
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#login label > span
{
  /* Style for the label text */
  display:block;
}

#login > label > input
{
  /* Style for the input itself. */
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all I recommend you changing the structure of your code to:

```html
...    
<form id="login" name="login" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="smart-green">    

  <h1>Login Form</h1> 

  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" />

  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

  <input type="submit" value="Send" />

</form>
```

And then the answers are:

a) access to the form

```
form#login{
...
}
```

b) the email address title and box

```
label[for=email]{
}
input[type=email]{
}
```

c) access the button

```
input[type=sbumit]{
...
}
```

Comment: You provide no accessibile link between your labels and the input they are for.  Either wrap your inputs in your labels or add `for` attributes to the labels and `id`s to the inputs.